# Schedule Event in Windows 7

Tags: windows, events, windows-7

How to make a scheduled event in win7? I used to have one in XP that ran every night, and I tried to make one in win7, but it doesn't run.. are they really hard to make work?

Comment: What did you do to try scheduling the event? You should be able to create and modify events from the Task Scheduler pretty easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NaV, try this article out.    http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/schedule-a-task .It should get you pointed in the right direction. This didn't take nearly as long as anwering your qestion with a question! :)